# How can I get a new IP address assigned to my NetGear CG3000D-RG?

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, ip, modem

I have a cable modem/router combo ( Netgear CG3000D-RG ).

For... reasons... I want to change my IP address.

Before, when I had just a standard cable modem, I was able to do this via windows by changing my IP address to something nonsensical... unfortunately I can neither remember the specific details of how I did it, nor can I locate the step-by-step to link, but it wouldn't apply here anyway because this is not a cable modem - it is a cable modem router.

I do not want to change my local IP address ( the one that my computer has assigned to it by the router ). I want to change the ***cable modem ip address***. How can I go about doing that?[image]

Comment: You can't. It's assigned by your ISP. You ISP *may* give you a new IP if you turn off your Modem for longer than the DHCP period. On the other hand, you *may* get exactly the same IP again (unless it has been given to another customer in the time your Modem was off).

Answer (score 0):

Changing your computer's IP in Windows (or even changing the private interface on your router) and changing the IP your ISP gives your router's public interface are two different things.

Your ISP generally utilizes DHCP which automatically assigns you an IP for a certain amount of time. After that time is up, either the lease is renewed, or a new IP is given. Some ISPs may give you a static IP upon request (and most likely payment).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your modem is assigned an IP address via DHCP, then you have to either call your ISP and ask them to clear your DHCP lease and reboot, or go to the Basic Settings and look for WAN IP Address and then the Expires field ([example](http://setuprouter.com/router/netgear/cg3000d-rg/lan-13385-large.htm)) and when you get very close to this time and date, disconnect your modem from the cable or pull the power, then wait until past the DHCP lease expiration time, and reconnect it... the amount of time you have to wait depends entirely on your ISP and how their DHCP is configured.

If you reconnect the modem too soon, and the DHCP server hasn't handed out your current address yet, you will likely get the same one back, if it has handed it out (or is configured not to reuse it after the lease is now renewed) then you should be issued a new IP address.

How long do you wait? Well, that is the unknown... it could be a few minutes or hours, or it could take days or even weeks depending on multiple factors like how busy your ISP's servers are, DHCP lease time, how many customers they have, how busy the DHCP scope is you are a part of is, and other things that are all outside of your control.

Comment: Often, devices will renew DHCP assigned addresses when only half the lease time has expired, restarting the lease time from the beginning.

Comment: @RonMaupin True... I forgot that, so this process would be even more trial and error to get it to work to get a new IP address.

Comment: I know that when we want to change addressing at a site, or VLAN, we need to set the lease time to something ridiculously low, like 30 minutes or an hour. That is done a couple of seeks ahead of time, so that every device has the new, short lease time prior to the change.

Comment: @RonMaupin Eh, internally where you have control it's easy... Just reboot the switches. Almost every piece of equipment will try renew if the connection drops and reconnects

Comment: Unfortunately, that is a huge no-no, causing an outage, which is a major mountain to climb. The engineers absolutely hate readdressing, but it is sometimes necessary. It would be easy if we could just shut down the access switches, make changes on the distribution switches, routers, etc., then power up the access switches, but that proves nearly impossible to get through the maze of necessary reviews, and there will always be some business group which flatly refuses to allow that sort of work.